# MPMoviePlayerController and local m3u8 files

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to load an m3u8 file that's saved to the local filesystem, but the MPMoviePlayerController refuses to play it, citing "m3u8 is not a supported media type". However, the same m3u8 file plays perfectly fine when I'm accessing it on a remote media server. Is there any workaround that can be used to play local m3u8 files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, according the RFC they lay out for m3u8 streaming, it can only be done over HTTP. Personally, I think it's kind of silly to require HTTP when the files can be readily accessed through the file protocol, but them's the breaks. I just used a [simple HTTP server](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) to serve the m3u8 file and the subsequent ts files.